# TypeScript: Parameter type in inherited method should be inferred

Tags: inheritance, typescript, type-inference, typechecking

The TypeScript compiler accepts the following code without signaling an error:

```
class S {
    f(p: number) {
        console.log(`${p + 1}`);
    }
}

class C extends S {
    f(p) {
        super.f(p)
    }
}

let a: C = new C();
let b: C = new C();

a.f(41);  // -> 42
b.f('x'); // -> x1
```

TypeScript being a statically typed language, shouldn't the compiler infer the parameter type of `p` in the inherited method `f` to `number`? Why is an assignment of the wrong typed string value left uncaught, producing weird behavior?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
class C extends S {
    f(p) {
        super.f(p)
    }
}
```

This code is equivalent to this code:

```
class C extends S {
    f(p: any) { // <---- parameter is 'any'
        super.f(p)
    }
}
```

This means you can invoke `C#f` with any argument type. This is a valid substitution for your class to make because it's valid to have a derived method be *more* general than its base method.

This behavior is understood to be a bit counterintuitive, so [there's a feature accepting PRs for this in the language](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/7011) to automatically type `p` as `string` in this case.

Comment: Thanks, Ryan, I agree that the substitution is valid with a more general parameter. Though, IMHO, the call `super.f(p)` should not be allowed with an argument of an undefined type (_any_). Is there a way to enforce such type checking by the compiler?